# IndexOutOfRangeException where there is no chance to get it

Tags: c#, xna, visual-studio-2017, monogame

I'm writing a game in XNA, created simple method to get subImages from textures, but everytime I use it, it throws an exception. I checked the variables and there is no chance to get out of bounds. Code for this two methods below:

```
public Color[] GetSubImage(Color[] colorData, int width, Rectangle rec)
    {
        Color[] color = new Color[rec.Width * rec.Height];

        for (int x = 0; x < rec.Width; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < rec.Height; y++)
            {
                color[x + y * rec.Width] = colorData[x + rec.X + (y + rec.Y) * width]; // Exception is thrown there
            }
        }
        return color;
    }

public void LoadSubImages(Texture2D sourceSpritesheet, List<Texture2D[]> destinationSprites)
    {
        int count = 0;
        Color[] imageData = new Color[sourceSpritesheet.Width * sourceSpritesheet.Height];
        Texture2D subImage;
        Rectangle sourceRec;

        destinationSprites = new List<Texture2D[]>();

        for (int i = 0; i < this.NUMFRAMES.Length; i++)
        {
            Texture2D[] bi = new Texture2D[this.NUMFRAMES[i]];

            for (int j = 0; j < this.NUMFRAMES[i]; j++)
            {
                sourceRec = new Rectangle(j * this.FRAMEWIDTHS[i], count, this.FRAMEWIDTHS[i], this.FRAMEHEIGHTS[i]);
                Color[] imagePiece = this.GetSubImage(imageData, sourceSpritesheet.Width, sourceRec);
                subImage = new Texture2D(Game1.Instance.GraphicsDevice, sourceRec.Width, sourceRec.Height);
                subImage.SetData<Color>(imagePiece);
                bi[j] = subImage;
            }

            destinationSprites.Add(bi);
            count += this.FRAMEHEIGHTS[i];
        }
    }
```

sourceSpritesheet is 368*550 big, FRAMEWIDTHS = 46, FRAMEHEIGTHS = 50, NUMFRAMES.Length = 11 (with values between 1-8)

Is there something that I can't see?

Comment: apparently `colorData[x + rec.X + (y + rec.Y) * width]` will use an index that is out of bounds, just set a breakpoint to see the values (check the items inside `colorData`).

Comment: Note that indexes are 0 based so if length is N maximum valid index is N - 1

Comment: Calculate indexes of arrays outside [ ] into variables, and check if they are inside bounds of arrays, before trying to get that index out of array.

Answer (score 1):

`colorData` has indices starting from `0` to `width * height`. You're accessing indices starting from `rec.X + rec.Y * width` to `(rec.X + width) + (height + rec.Y) * height`. If `rec.X` or `rec.Y` is greater than `0` (which will happen, given how you construct your rectangles), this will go out of bounds. .NET Framework arrays are luckily working correctly, universe is safe...

Answer (score 1):

`colorData` is 202,400 in size

In the worst case scenario :

`colorData[x + rec.X + (y + rec.Y) * width];`

```
x = 45
rec.x = 7*46 = 322
y = 50
rec.y = 11*50 = 550
width = 368
```

due to the order of operations your formula would execute like so:

`x + rec.X + ((y + rec.Y) * width)`

`45 + 322 + ((50 + 550) * 368)`

`367 + (600 * 368)`

`221,167`

and 221,167 is greater then `colorData` size of 202,400. So in conclusion it is most definitely possible to go out of bounds with your function. I would recommend you rewrite it as it seems to be a horrid case of spaghetti code.

Comment: Thanks, I just found the answer. I calculated on paper some single points and indexes, so on the line `color[x + y * rec.Width] = colorData[x + rec.X + (y + rec.Y) * width]` i changed the `width` to `rec.Width` and... everything works just fine. It's my fault I hadn't noticed that.